# How to prove the identity of the following Boolean equations?

Tags: boolean-logic, simplify

Using boolean manipulation, how could I prove these two sides are equal? For number one, I was considering manipulating both sides until they match. I can't seem to manipulate it correctly though.

1. wy + w'yz' + wxz + w'xy' = wy + w'xz' + x'yz' + xy'z
2. ad' + a'b + c'd + b'c = (a' + b' + c' + d')(a + b + c + d)

Thanks for any help or input!

Comment: If this is a homework question, this is not the proper place to ask. This is about coding questions. But what are the "'" anyway? Inversion?

Comment: I guess I assumed digital logic would be applicable to this forum. But yeah, the notation I'm using is:

( ' = NOT ) 

( + = OR )

( * or multiplication = AND )

Answer (score 0):

for 1:

Simply compare for which of the 2^4=16 input combinations both sides of the equation evaluate to true:

```
w y z x
0 0 0 1
0 0 1 1
0 1 0 0
0 1 0 1
1 0 1 1
1 1 0 0
1 1 0 1
1 1 1 0
1 1 1 1
```

for 2:

You could do the same as for 1. or multiply-out both brackets, remove false terms like a'a, delete duplicate terms and compare both sides term by term.

Both sides are in fact equal. They evaluate to true for the following input combinations:

```
a b c d
0 0 1 0
0 1 0 0
0 1 1 0
0 0 0 1
0 0 1 1
0 1 0 1
0 1 1 1
1 0 0 0
1 0 1 0
1 1 0 0
1 0 1 1
1 0 0 1
1 0 1 1
1 1 0 1
```